# Comparing image URLs

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Hi I got a set of codes here, which compares images' URL. This was from a library. An multiple imagepicker,
I know that in these codes, that the otherUrls are the images picked, while the selfUrls are the one that the photolibrary/camera roll contains.

Can someone please help me, on making this a shortcut, to not compare to every single URLs, to just skip to it, or fast comparing. Hope someone could help me. cause when it compares to all the selfUrls, it crashes. due to too much picture.

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other
{
  if (other == self)
  return YES;
  if (!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]])
  return NO;

  ALAsset *otherAsset = (ALAsset *)other;
  NSDictionary *selfUrls = [self valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];
  NSDictionary *otherUrls = [otherAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];
  return [selfUrls isEqualToDictionary:otherUrls];
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I don't comprehend "to not compare to every single URLs, to just skip to it, or fast comparing"? What do you want it to do, and what do you mean with "shortcut"?

Comment: the otherURLs is comparing with all the selfUrls. so for exxample I have 2000 images, it will compare it to all of it. that's why my app crashes, I dont know how to make a shorter version. or shortcut version, will skip to comparing ot shorter way. or just adding an index to it. hope you could help. thankyou

Comment: Well, as cory said, I don't think there is a 'shortcut' to comparing two NSDictionary's. Apart from doing pointer equation of course, but this will likely not work in your case. But I also don't think this is the reason your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question this is fairly simple. I won't write the exact code for you to do it but will give you some pointers.

First off we  need to find what the format of the camera roll URL looks like (so we know which ones to skip over).

So to do this create a simple call to launch the camera roll. It will have a delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` that we will use. It returns the information associated with the image you selected. We can pull the URL of the image easily.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

     //Get the image url
     NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

     //Convert url to string
     NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

    //Print it out
    NSLog(@"Our string format = %@", urlString);
}
```

Now that we know what the format of the camera roll URL. What you can do know is look and say, "Ok, the first 10 characters of each URL pulled from the camera roll is the same". When you loop through checking your URLs, check the first 10 characters. If they differ from the camera roll format then you know its *not* from the camera roll (mouthful).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have the didFinishpickingmedia, but the otherURLs is comparing with all the selfUrls. so for exxample I have 2000 images, it will compare it to all of it. that's why my app crashes, I dont know how to make a shorter version. or shortcut version, will skip to comparing ot shorter way. or just adding an index to it. hope you could help. thankyou

Comment: So you have an array of 2000 image URLs. Correct? And you need to search through them? Correct? I don't believe there to be any "shortcut" to not searching through all.